# How to correctly import web3::api::eth::Eth pub fn transaction_count in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-web3

I'm new to Rust. I'm trying to import the function `web3::api::eth::Eth pub fn transaction_count` but unable to do so. I have web3 crate installed in my Carg.toml file:

```
web3 = "0.18.0"
```

Since hovering over the `transaction_count` function showed:

```
pub fn transaction_count(&self, address: Address, block: Option<BlockNumber>) -> CallFuture<U256, T::Out>
```

Hence I tried importing it like this:

```
use web3::api::eth::Eth::{self, transaction_count};
```

But I'm unable to `Cmd + click` on eth but I'm able to do so on api.

How should I import it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full example (based on [this](https://github.com/tomusdrw/rust-web3)) that works

```
use web3::{Web3, transports};


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> web3::Result<()> {
    // bsc node
    let transport = transports::Http::new("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/")?;
    let web3 = Web3::new(transport);

    println!("Calling accounts.");
    let mut accounts = web3.eth().accounts().await?;
    println!("Accounts: {:?}", accounts);
    // Cake token
    accounts.push("0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82".parse().unwrap());

    println!("Calling transaction count");
    let count = web3.eth().transaction_count(accounts[0], None).await?;
    println!("Transaction count: {:?}", count);
    Ok(())
}
```

Cake token has transaction count of 1 which is not extremely interesting but you can use some other address if you wish